# Rebooting windows 10 with a mapped network drive open and restore folders gives pointless error and closes those windows

Tags: windows-10, nas

I have a mapped network drive on a NAS.
I have set windows to "restore previous folder windows at logon"

Every time I reboot my PC, all file explorer windows that are opened to a mapped network drive will give the error

[image: restoring network connections error]

It will show a blank address bar so I don't even know which exactly location it was (so I can't go one by one and manually reopen those windows before hitting ok). When I click on OK (the only option) it will close that folder.

This happens because it takes some time after logon for the NAS to be connected to. Furthermore there seems to be some faulty handling on the bootup version of this.

Is there some way to make windows not do this? For example, if I open a mapped network drive folder, then I turn off my nas, I will get the same message. However it will show me the current address. And If I restore the NAS connection before clicking OK then it will actually NOT close the window. So I can easily refresh it to reconnect. This is vastly preferable compared to what it does on startup.

Comment: Since you say this happens when the PC is "rebooted" to me it sounds like the group policy or correlated registry setting needs set to force the OS to wait for the network to be fully initialized before it allows you to log onto the OS. It almost sounds like Windows 10 is allowing you to sign onto it before the network is fully connected and since it is trying to map the network drives and the network is not fully initialize you are getting that error message.

Comment: To resolve run `gpedit.msc` and then navigate: **Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Logon ->** ENABLE the "*Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon*"... or the registry: `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` with a SyncForegroundPolicy (DWORD) = 1..... if you determine any of this helps, I'm happy to add as an answer so just ping me back and let me know but that's what it sounds like to me.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I had already tried that and it doesn't work unfortunately. I am thinking there is an additional step that needs to be taken

Comment: Is it just on reboot and does it happen without a reboot if you logoff and then log back on?

Comment: Read over these suggested answers on this post in case you find helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/630268/an-error-occurred-while-connecting-drive-to-share-the-local-device-name-is.... The service start or perhaps restart, the autodiscovery issue, and the NIC power management settings. Otherwise try connect via `\\<IPAddress>\private` and see if that makes any difference in case you have a DNS issue going on at reboot so `IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS` on the host too and test. Again, this only happens at reboot and not if you only logoff and then back on, correct?